# How to debug theme (Theme is causing pages to have no style or HTML <head> section)

Tags: theme-development, debug

I have a WordPress theme given to me by a client, so not familiar with it at all. Activating the Twenty Sixteen theme resolves the problem, so it's not a plugin but definitely the client's theme.

Certain pages are being displayed with no  or  sections. Just the `<div>....</div>` fragment.

The content of the page is therefore just black text on white background. No errors in log files. Have set the following debug options in `wp-config.php`:-

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
@ini_set( 'display_errors',1 );
```

But no errors shown.

Any ideas where in the theme I should start looking?

Comment: Can you post the content of the header.php file in the theme, or just the first few lines so we can see if there's a glaringly obvious problem. Also where are you hosting the website? As there may be an issue with your environment not having the same setup as their development environment. And have you seen this theme fully functioning in a development environment?

Comment: Did you check if your templates include `get_header()`, or, if not, `wp_head()` (should be called in header.php)

Comment: start by checking the template files. If you want to debug a theme, it might be helpful to know what file you're looking at in your browser. Try adding a line of text to tell you what file it is. beyond that the other two comments have it covered

Comment: Install https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ it should tell you what is getting loaded and why. From there follow the https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ and make sure wp_head and wp_footer are getting called.

Comment: thanks @jgraup for the pointers. that's a useful plugin. The theme was always calling front-page.php rather than page.php. Not sure if this is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the helpful comments, turned out it was the CiviCRM 4.7 plugin that was using a 'base page' and always calling `page.php` as the default theme template. BUT our Theme was not implementing `page.php` so no `<html>` or `<head>` content was being injected.

Debugged by installing [XDebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/install) on the server running on port 9000 and [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) on the client (there are free ones, but this is so easy to set up!) and finally the 'Chrome XDebug helper extension'. Sorry, no more links due to reputation :(

Stepping through the code showed the template hierarchy that had been implemented by the original theme developers, always bypassing `page.php` and calling `partials/front-page.php`, which is a common pattern used in some themes, e.g. Virtue.

So the resolution was to add a filter to the bottom of the 'functions.php' file in the Theme route and override the CiviCRM plugin action that was calling page.php:-

`add_filter( 'civicrm_basepage_template', 'front_page_for_civi' );
function front_page_for_civi( $template ) {
    if ($template=='page.php') {
        return 'partials/front-page.php';
    }
    return $template;
}`

Depending on the plug-in, this filter will obviously need to be called something other than `civicrm_basepage_template`, but hope it points people in the right direction!

Kudos to @christian-wach for originally answering this in the CiviCRM stack exchange forum.